# Firing An Employee For Innocent Absenteeism

Tags: management

I have an employee who works part time in a small company (3 employees) in New Jersey whose duties include daily data input on a specialized program and phone calls with customers. The employee has a chronic respiratory problem and is absent on occasion for several days or a week or more. Our company needs this position filled daily. Can we discharge the employee without fear of a litigation claim?

Comment: VTC - Legal advice is off-topic on Workplace.

Comment: You will make your employee wealthy beyond the dreams of avarice.

Comment: New Jersey is an employment-at-will state. Meaning you can terminate an employee at any time without reason or notice.

Answer (score 2):

IANAL but FMLA doesn't seem to apply because of the size of the company. There may be a NJ equivalent but again I expect that it wouldn't apply to such a small company. That said just because you aren't doing anything illegal and would likely win any case against you it doesn't prevent them from filing a case and being a pain if they want to be. I would try to work it out with the employee first.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_and_Medical_Leave_Act_of_1993

Comment: "I would try to work it out with the employee first.". Also, consider the impact on morale for the other employees. You will send the message "If you get ill, we'll fire you" - that may not be in your best interest. Consider other solutions (e.g, offer reduced hours and hire someone else, allow working from home, ergonomic accomodations etc.).